# For all active sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VB script to autofit merged cells height, but it only works for the first sheet/current sheet of the workbook.

The VBA Script is originally from [Autofit Merged Cells with VBA](https://www.thesmallman.com/autofit-merged-cells), and I made some slightly range change.

I'd like to make all my available/active sheets to run this same VB script. So, I added the following SlectedSheets code to the AutofixMergedCellHeigh VB script, but it didn't work.

Does anyone could help out? Thanks a lot!

AutofixMergedCellHeight:

[image]

```
Sub FixMerged()
    Dim mw As Single
    Dim cM As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cw As Double
    Dim rwht As Double
    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Cell Ranges below, change to suit.
    ar = Array("B32", "B33")
    For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range(Range(ar(i)).MergeArea.Address)
        With rng
           .MergeCells = False
            cw = .Cells(1).ColumnWidth
            mw = 0
        For Each cM In rng
            cM.WrapText = True
            mw = cM.ColumnWidth + mw
        Next
        mw = mw + rng.Cells.Count * 0.66
        .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = mw
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        rwht = .RowHeight
        .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = cw
        .MergeCells = True
        .RowHeight = rwht
        End With
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

I also add a new script to loop through all of the worksheets in the workbook by using a 'For Each' loop, and inserted calls for SelectSheets and FixMerged. But this way only works on the current single sheet too.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    For Each Current In Worksheets
        SelectSheets
        FixMerged
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Pls edit your post and copy and paste the code (in text)

Comment: @Ricardo, the images of code should show up. Please let me know if you can see them, and looking forward your help. Thanks!

Comment: Please copy and paste your code *as text* - images of code do not help anyone trying to help you with your problem: we'd first have to type it all out before testing...

Comment: @Tim, thanks for letting me know! I just updated the code as text and look forward to your review and help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Passing a Worksheet Object to Another Procedure

**The Calling Procedure**

```vb
Sub FixMergedAll()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        FixMergedCells ws
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**The Called Procedure**

- `' ***` designates the locations of the introduced changes. For the rest, you're on your own.

```vb
Sub FixMergedCells(ByVal ws As Worksheet) ' ***
    
    Dim mw As Single
    Dim cM As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cw As Double
    Dim rwht As Double
    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim i As Long ' ***
    
    'Cell Ranges below, change to suit.
    ar = Array("B32", "B33")
    
    For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar) ' ***
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        Set rng = ws.Range(ar(i)).MergeArea ' ***
        
        With rng
           
           .MergeCells = False
            cw = .Cells(1).ColumnWidth
            mw = 0
            
            For Each cM In rng
                cM.WrapText = True
                mw = cM.ColumnWidth + mw
            Next
            
            mw = mw + rng.Cells.Count * 0.66
            .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = mw
            .EntireRow.AutoFit
            rwht = .RowHeight
            .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = cw
            .MergeCells = True
            .RowHeight = rwht
        
        End With
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome. I have simplified this `Set rng = ws.Range(ar(i)).MergeArea` only a few minutes ago. Also, I have only now noticed that you are under `Option Base 1` so the `1` could have stayed although you're not using the indexes of the array in any calculations so rather stick with the recommended `LBound(ar)`. But using `Option Base 1` isn't recommended at all (unless you're forced to).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations and suggestions! I'll remove "Option Base 1" from the code since it's not necessary. I appreciate your kind help and time.

Comment: @MMMKKK if the answer worked, please remember to mark it (tic the green checkmark), so others can find it